# How do you commit code as a different user?

Tags: git, command-line, commit

I want to be able to do this for a script. I'm essentially re-creating the entire version history of some code in Git - it currently uses a different version control system. I need the script to be able to add in the commits to Git while preserving the commit's original author (and date).

Assuming I know the commit author and the date/time the change was made, is there a Git command that allows me to do this? I'm assuming there is, because git-p4 does something similar. I'm just asking for the best way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried using fast-import?

Comment: I agree, [fast-import](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fast-import.html) is likely to be the best way to go. You could use *git commit* (or more properly the underlying plumbing: *hash-object*, *update-index*, *write-tree*, *commit-tree*, *update-ref*, etc.), but *fast-import* would be, well, faster.

Comment: I did think of fast-import, but as I'm quite the git beginner myself, I decided to use the basic commands. To be perfectly honest I do not fully understand how fast-import works and am therefore a little hesitant to use it until I understand it better. Yes, it will be a lot slower using commit, but at least I will know what to expect - especially while debugging.

Comment: git commit --author="Name <name@example.com>" -a -m "commit msg"

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Check out the `--author` option for `git commit`:

From the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---authorltauthorgt):

> `--author=<author>`
>
> Override the commit author. Specify an explicit author
> using the standard `A U Thor <author@example.com>` format. Otherwise
> `<author>` is assumed to be a pattern
> and is used to search for an existing
> commit by that author (i.e. `rev-list --all -i --author=<author>`); the commit author is then copied from the
> first such commit found.

Comment: Also, the `--date` option to override the date.

Comment: Can you give a specific example, everything I try

Comment: @Tim Henigan: It looks like documentation is now hosted on [Github](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-commit.html) so the *man page* link you posted is dead.  Can you confirm the new page is the same thing (in case there are other answers that need links updated)?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: I updated the URL.  The GitHub pages are correct. I updated my link since the man pages are no longer hosted on kernel.org.  Thanks for letting me know about the change.

Comment: Here is what I ended up using: `git commit -a --author="$user_details" --date="submit_date $submit_time" --file=/tmp/commit_msg`

Answer (score 152):

Just to add to this: The `--author` option mentioned in the accepted answer will only override the *author*, not the *committer* information of the commit.

That is the correct behavior in most cases, but if for some reason you need to manually override the **committer information** as well, use the `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` environment variables (there is a `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` as well). See [Git-Internals-Environment-Variables](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables)

```
$ GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="New Name" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="name@email.com" git commit --author="New Name <name@email.com>"
```

This will make the commit look like it was authored **and** committed by the specified user.

Comment: ... and to see the difference: `git log --pretty=fuller`

Comment: Perfect. This is what I wanted and I could have never find the git internals man page.

Comment: Another way to see the difference: `git log --pretty='%cn %cd - %an %ad' HEAD` where `%cn %cd` - committer name, date and `%an %ad` - author name, date.

Answer (score 28):

Use -c option along with git-commit to override any previous configuration. It will not touch your global/project configuration. For example, to override name and email:

```
git -c user.name='My Name' -c user.email='my@email.com' commit -m "Custom message"
```

However, if you intend to keep it as an additional setting, I would suggest to use an alias. Edit your `~/.gitconfig` file and append a new alias for each non-default user and email.

```
[user]
  name = My Name
  email = default@email.com

[alias]
  commit-x = -c user.name='My X Name' -c user.email='mr_x@email.com' commit
  commit-y = -c user.name='My Y Name' -c user.email='mr_y@email.com' commit
  commit-z = -c user.name='My Z Name' -c user.email='mr_z@email.com' commit
```

Alias will be applied globally. Test it.

```
git commit -m "Custom message with committer and author My Name <default@email.com>"
git commit-x -m "Custom message with committer and author My X Name <mr_x@email.com>"
git commit-y -m "Custom message with committer and author My Y Name <mr_y@email.com>"
git commit-z -m "Custom message with committer and author My Z Name <mr_z@email.com>"
```

Comment: I get an error: "fatal: Option -m cannot be combined with -c/-C/-F."  On removing "-m", getting another error: "fatal: could not lookup commit user.email=<provided_user_name>"

Comment: @ArnabBiswas Thanks for your feedback. I have just edited my answer because I had typed the first example wrongly: commit must go after of config options.