# How to push someone else's patch to master?

Tags: git

I have applied a patch using

`git apply someone-else.patch`

tested that it works ok and it does so next, I want to push that change to master.

The problem is I want to do that without re-authoring a commit for it (i.e. since the patch is not my work, but someone else's, I am keen they keep the authorship credit on the git log).

At the moment the applied patch is not showing up on my gitlog so I am assuming there is another step but I have no recollection of what that step is from having done this quite a while ago in the past and not needed to repeat it again very often. Google is not being forthcoming here, so my guess is I am forgetting the name of the appropriate command.

To summarise, what can I do next to get this patch pushed without making a fresh commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up following the instructions found on [this blog](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/) but added one step to make the procedure work properly

The procedure:

1. `git apply someone-else.patch`
2. Test it works
3. `git add changed-files`
4. `git am --signoff < someone-else.patch`
5. `git push`

Answer (score 3):

> To summarise, what can I do next to get this patch pushed without making a fresh commit?

Well, you have to make a fresh commit.
But at least, you can [make said commit with the right author name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3696994/6309):

```
git commit --author="xxx <xxx@email.com>" -m "patch from xxx"
```

(see an example at "[git commit as different user without email / or only email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612125/6309)")