# Can I used more than 1 account using git bash

Tags: git, github, authentication, account

I have different respos in bitbucket, but I want to commit every repo with seprate account and facing problem to login more than account using gitbash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you commit code as a different user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696938/how-do-you-commit-code-as-a-different-user)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig
Duplicate (Use --local)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple github accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `--author` option for `git commit`